# Run a .cmd via VBScript based on volume changes

Tags: vbscript, cmd

I am trying to get this code to call a .cmd from my flash drive whenever it is plugged in, based on a change in volume, but it only displays the event type, not run the program.

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2")
Set evtDevice = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_VolumeChangeEvent")

WScript.Echo "Waiting for events ..."
Do
    Set objReceivedEvent = evtDevice.NextEvent
    'report an event
    WScript.Echo " Win32_Device Changed event occurred" & vbNewLine
    If objReceivedEvent.EventType = 1 Then
        WScript.Echo "Type = Config Changed"
    ElseIf objReceivedEvent.EventType = 2 Then
        WScript.Echo "Type = Device Arrived"

        Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Volume")
        For Each objItem in colItems
            WScript.Echo objItem.DriveType
            If objItem.DriveType = 2 Then
                WScript.Echo objItem.DriveType & " " & objItem.Name & " " & objItem.DriveLetter
            End If
        Next
    ElseIf objReceivedEvent.EventType = 3 Then
        WScript.Echo "Type = Device Left"
    ElseIf objReceivedEvent.EventType = 4 Then
        WScript.Echo "Type = Computer Docked"
    End If
Loop

If objReceivedEvent.EventType = 2 Then
    objShell.Run "D:\Melons V0.9.cmd"
```

These last two lines are faulty, and I cannot determine the cause. Suggestions?

Comment: Replace  `Wscript.Echo objItem.DriveType & " " & objItem.Name & " " & objItem.driveletter` with your last line. Put at top of script `set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")`.

Comment: VBScript's help file is here - https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=2764.

Comment: As Noodles already pointed out, you never initialize `objShell`, so there's nothing to call a `Run` method from. Also, if you want to wrap a short `If..Then` statement (one without `End If`) you need to use the line continuation operator `_`, otherwise the statement must be in a single line. Plus, you have an infinite loop there, so the last two lines are never reached. Either put the `Run` call inside the loop, or put it in a procedure that you call from inside the loop.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your time and the detailed answer.